# Localized Markdown resources

Tags: c#, localization, internationalization, markdown, translation

I've got a web project that's supposed to support localization (in the future). One issue I've run into is that some pieces of text that are conceptually one piece have multiple styles: bolding some parts for emphasis, header styling for certain sections, embedded links. Right now our solution is to piecemeal the whole together which is undesirable because a translator will have to look at these fragmented pieces and try to figure out what was intended—not ideal.

The best compromise I can see is to allow Markdown in our localization resources. Unfortunately, I can't find any solid examples that cover the translator-to-code solution. What demos, examples, tools and technologies are relevant to my need? A brief overview of how they fit into the solution would be helpful.

I've stated the generic question, but my specific setup is a C# MVC project using resx files for localization. We're also using AngularJS, but we've largely kept localization to the C# side of things.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. If you found solution please write an answer